# How to order multiple new columns after a specific column in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel

Is there a nice way to do this? I currently do it by listing the columns in reverse order of the order I want like this:

```
Schema::table('some_table', function($table){
    $table->string('new_col_2')->after('existing_col'); //How to specify that this should come after new_col_1?
    $table->string('new_col_1')->after('existing_col');
});
```

Comment: May I ask you - out of personal curiosity - why the order of the db fields are important to you?

Comment: I suppose because having a logical order makes it easier to human-parse the data

Comment: You mean by looking via PHP Admin (or any other DB Viewer) right inside the DB?

Comment: Yes, better to see something like [id, name, address_line_1, address_line_2, age, date_created] than [address_line_2, date_created, age, address_line_1, id, name]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try :

```
Schema::table('some_table', function($table){
  $table->string('new_col_1')->after('existing_col');
  $table->string('new_col_2')->after('new_col_1');
}
```

Comment: Yes, just realised I had mistyped a column name which is why the migration failed doing it like this!

Answer (score 4):

If `existing_col` is present, I think it is possible to call the next columns you create in 'normal' order:

```
Schema::table('some_table', function($table){
    $table->string('new_col_1')->after('existing_col');
    $table->string('new_col_2')->after('new_col_1');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Another and better option would be

```
Schema::table('some_table', function($table){
    $table->after('existing_col', function ($table) {
       $table->string('new_col_1');
       $table->string('new_col_2');
   });
});
```